# cPanel user starting with Digital Ocean VPS

Tags: mysql

I've been using cPanel my whole life. Just switched to digital ocean to play around with their droplets.

I'm having trouble creating mysql dbs with digital ocean. I'm not good with unix shell. Also having trouble trying to ssh into account using mysql workbench gui. It keeps giving me error that my login credentials are invalid.

I've changed the default admin password for mysql, but I can't seem to login into my vps with either the new password or the default password.

I've tried installing phpmyadmin, but I prefer not to use this because it is not secure. With cpanel there is a page where you can create dbs and setup privileges easily.

I've read some tutorials, but I would I just like to know what the best 'workflow' is for VPS setting up mysql dbs. Everything is so easy with cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't install any other soft , just go into ssh and learn your way .

I dont know how you intalled mysql but if you installed it using some kind of images or preloaded images in DO.

When you log into ssh you are given the mysql password .

Then from here you can start reading some mysql tutorials to add new database / users  since its pretty simple .

Most time i use Navicat to manage My DB's .